# React JS pass class as variable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to create something like below in ReactJS but i can't figure out how and I most definitly don't want to use DangerouslySetInnerHTML. It's just a stupid example but i hope it makes clear what i want. Thanks for helping me out!

```
var page = {
    title: <ReactTitle title={this.props.page.name} />
    name: "Me myself and I"
};

var ReactTitle = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <h1>{this.props.title}
        );
    }
})
var NewPage = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="row">
                {this.props.page.title}
                <div className="page-header"><h1>{this.props.page.name}</h1></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
})

React.render(
    <NewPage page={page} />
);
```

Comment: In most cases you can just do this  ```<ReactTitle title={this.props.page.name} />``` instead of ```{this.props.page.title}```. But you are prolly asking to know if its possible to to it as you describe right?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Lets say you're working in a modularized way (for instance using [browserify](http://browserify.org/)) then you could just `require()` your `<ReactTitle />` inside your `<Newpage />` instead of passing it.

Comment: Well because most of my classes are useable for all pages (in my project). But some parts are slidely different. Instead of normalizing it to much I was thinking about this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `React.createElement`, like so

```
var page = {
    title: React.createElement(ReactTitle, {title: "My awesome Title"}),
    name: "Me myself and I"
};
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/12514/)

But in my opinion better use `ReactTitle` inside `NewPage`, like so

```
<div className="row">
  <ReactTitle title={this.props.page.title} /> 
  <div className="page-header"><h1>{this.props.page.name}</h1></div>
</div>
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/12516/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution, with thanks to @Alexander

```
//Example
var page1 = {
    title: [
        React.createElement("h1", "", "This is my page title");
        React.createElement("div", {className:"page-header"}, "This is the header of page 1");
    ],
    name: "Me myself and I"
};
//So page2, which is slidely different:
//Example
var page2 = {
    title: [
        React.createElement("h2", {className:"h2"}, "Title part",
            React.createElement("span", {className:"silent"}, "Silent part of page title")
        ),
        React.createElement("div", {className:"page-header"}, "This is the header of page 2");
    ],
    name: "Me myself and I"
};
```